# Connection refused SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

If you execute sql direct requests through phpmyadmin, then the request is executed correctly. If you execute a query through a web script to a table, then it is not executed

```
#0: > INSERT INTO `UltraCosmeticsData` (username, treasureKeys)
    VALUES ('{user}', 3)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE treasureKeys = treasureKeys + VALUES (treasureKeys);
#1: Connection refused
```

Comment: check that `phpmyadmin` users and web script user do match. run `SELECT USER();` from `phpmyadmin`. then run the same command with web script. Also databases you connect to must be the same.

Comment: In your web code, check for errors after connecting.  _That_ is probably where the problem is.